# Filling a singly linked list nodes

Tags: c, list

So for my class in C, we are told to create an array of Contacts (telephone numbers and names)  with nodes containing the address of the next Contact in the list.

I'm new to pointers and I get the concept of them, but they are confusing. I will comment my thought process and what I think I am doing. We we're provided a lot of this code. I only implemented the Contact structure and disaster of words that form the addLast function.

```
typedef struct Contact
{
    int *Next;
    char *Name;
    char *Tel;

} Contact;


Contact *start=NULL; //This start variable dictates the first node in the list.

void builtList(Contact*);
void addLast(Contact*);
void printList();

int main()
{
    Contact contacts[7]=
    {
        {NULL,"Dennis","0203/123456"}, 
        {NULL,"Chantal","0177/3123345"},
        {NULL,"Robert","0163/9295986"},
        {NULL,"Bjoern","040 - 123232345"},
        {NULL,"Andreas","+49 178 11903123"},
        {NULL,"Jenny","+41 119 34544345"},
        {NULL,"Zeuss","0162-123-4531698"},
    };

    builtList(contacts);
    printList();


return 0;
}

void builtList(Contact contacts[]) //This function was written for us. 
//I would prefer to modify this as little as possible.
{
    Contact *ptr=NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        ptr=&contacts[i];
        addLast(ptr);
    }

}

void addLast(Contact *AddressOfCurrent)
{ 

/* This is the function I am struggling with. We are told this function is to 
"add a Contact element to the end of the singly linked list". From what I understand,
It obtains the ADDRESS of the next node and places it into the current node. Thereby
establishing a link between two elements in the list. My friend did this without
importing the contacts[] array and just using a '*temp' array. This confuses me
greatly. How do I establish links between elements if I don't have the elements
with me? */

    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = AddressOfCurrent; //I can figure out how to establish the start.
    } else
    {
?????????
    }
}
```

To clarify, here is my task;

> Your task is to implement a Contact List that uses a singly linked
>   list.
>   In computer science, a linked list (or more clearly, "singly linked
>   list") is a data structure that consists of a sequence of nodes each
>   of which contains a reference (i.e., a link) to the next node in the
>   sequence.
>
> Realise the following structures/Variables
>
> Create a structure called Contact which has the following variables
>   Contact *next (pointer to the next element in the List) char *name
>   (used to store the contact's name) char *tel (used to store the
>   contacts telephone number) Create a global Contact* variable called
>   "start" which points to the start element of the singly linked list.
>   Realise the following functions (for prototypes see linked source
>   code):
>
> addLast(Contact*): add a Contact element to the end of the singly
>   linked list (a few other unrelated functions)
>
> For all listed operations youe have to write a new C function each.

Comment: You can think of a single-linked list as a stack. I also urge you to do this on paper first before trying to code anything.

Comment: The reason nobody's answered your question is because it's difficult to understand. The fact that your list nodes are stored in an array suggests that you're just supposed to mimic pointers using array indices. If you can edit your question to state the exact wording of the assignment, that might help people to understand.

Comment: @ooga Alright I appended the actual task below and got rid of some unnecessary comments, shifted some code to make it more legible. You are correct, we are supposed to mimic pointers using array indices. That however is proving to be confusing when everything isn't in the same function.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't sound like you're supposed to use array indices at all. It looks like you're supposed to use real pointers. But it is strange that the data is already there in an array. I can't comprehend your assignment at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only actual *question* I see in your post is this one:

> My friend did this without
>   importing the contacts[] array and just using a '*temp' array. This confuses me
>   greatly. How do I establish links between elements if I don't have the elements
>   with me?

Since we don't have your friends code at hand, it's hard to evaluate, so let's forget that. Without adding parameters to the `addUser()` function, you'd need a global, which you have declared:

```
Contact *start=NULL;
```

So that's accessible everywhere.   And you are on the right track in `addContact()`:

```
if (!start) {
```

But if start isn't NULL, then you need to walk the list to the end via the `Next` pointer, implying another necessity for the `addContact()` function:

```
AddressOfCurrent->Next = NULL;
```

This means each added node has a NULL next pointer.  When another node is added to that one, then you need to the previous last node `Next` to non-null:

```
???->Next = AddressOfCurrent;
```

`???` here is the node at the end of the current list you'll find by walking it.  It's the only one where `Next == NULL` ;)

Comment: "But if start isn't NULL, then you need to walk the list to the end" I've been trying to make this work for at least 3 hours. Reading that line gave the most "OF COURSE!" reaction i've felt in quite a long time. We don't need the actual array, we have the addresses. Thank you!

Comment: A final question is why write AddressOfCurrent->Next instead of AddressOfCurrent.Next?

Comment: What's the difference though?

Comment: The pointer holds the *address of* the struct; the struct itself can be accessed by dereferencing: `*p`, so member `foo` can be accessed with `(*p).foo`, or the much more normative shorthand, `p->foo`.  Note that `p.foo` won't work. `->` and `.` are both **[operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)**.